# SVG Size and Color

Tags: html, svg

I've been looking at using SVGs on my site, I wish to color them via CSS, I've looked at some blogs which suggest using the object tag:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/static/test.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

I'm now trying to do two things, colour the svg, I've tried using:

```
fill: red;
```

But no luck.

And size it, I've tried this on the object:

```
width="150px"
```

But no luck.

Comment: Did you put the fill: red in the test.svg file or in a css file referenced from the test.svg file which is the right thing to do or did you put your css in the html file or a css file referenced from the html file which is the wrong thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `<svg>` object to make it possible. A good solution could be to use the [iconic's SVGInjector](https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector) so you can load it from another file and keep your code clean.